# Angular custom pipe with number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

I have two inputs for the user. The first input is the main number. 
The second input is the number of zeroes behind the main number.

The basic `{{ mainNumber | number: '1.5'}}`works. Here I will have five zeroes behind the main number. But I want that *5* to be dynamic, to be what the user has input in the second field.

This is the component.html:

```
  Number <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="mainNumber" placeholder="Enter the number"> &nbsp;
  Zero: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="zeroNumber" placeholder="Enter the zero"> <br>
  <hr>
  <b> Number: </b>{{mainNumber}} &nbsp;
  <b> Zero: </b> {{zeroNumber}} <br>
  <!-- {{ mainNumber | number: '1.10'}} -->

  Final number: {{ mainNumber | mojpipe }}
```

This is the **component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  mainNumber: number = 0;
  zeroNumber: number = 0;
  title = 'shopping-project';
}
```

This is the custom pipe I tried to build, **mypipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'mojpipe' })
export class AddZero implements PipeTransform{
    testTwo: number = 1;
    transform(size: number){
        return (size + "."+ this.testDva);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use the variable inside your pipe expression:

```
{{ mainNumber | number: ('1.' + zeroNumber }}
```

Comment: I just get this error in the console: `mainNumber is not a number' for pipe 'DecimalPipe' `

Comment: I fixed the old answer. This worked great for me:
`Final number: {{ mainNumber | number: ('1.' + zeroNumber) }}`